# What algorithm and data structure would fit the use case of overlapping traffic on a roadway

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, greedy

I have a problem where I have a road that has multiple entry points and exits. I am trying to model it so that traffic can flow into an entry and go out the exit. The entry points also act as exits. All the entrypoints are labelled 1 to 10 (i.e. we have 10 entry and exits).

A car is allowed to enter and exit at any point *however* the entry is always lower number than the exit. For example a car enters at 3 and goes to 8, it cannot go from 3 to 3 or from 8 to 3.

After every second the car moves one unit on the road. So from above example the car goes from 3 to 4 after one second. I want to continuously accept cars at different entrypoints and update their positions after each second. However I cannot accept a car at an entry if there is already one present at that location.

All cars are travelling at the same speed of 1 unit per second and all are same size and occupy just the space at the point they are in. Once a car reaches its destination, its removed from the road.

For all new cars that come into the entrypoint and are waiting, we need to assign a waiting time. How would that work? For example it needs to account for when it is able to find a slot where it can be put on the road.

Is there an algorithm that this problem fits into?
What data structure would I model this in - for example for each entrypoints, I was thinking something like a queue or like an ordered map and for the road, maybe a linkedlist?

Comment: I don't see where the "roads" are if cars move from entry point N to entry point N+1 each second - is there any space between entry points or not?

Comment: @tar Yes all entrypoints are spaced one unit apart. There is only one road. At each entrypoint there maybe a request to go to a random exit. For example a car entering at 3 could request to go to 7. Another one at 5 could request to go 9. Another one may already be at 6 etc.

The main thing I am looking for is to find a way to give a wait time to a new car that requests entry. To calculate that, I would have to account for priority of previous requests of cars at other locations and where they exit along with how much time those would take and when can this current car be put on the road.

Comment: Before you can choose a data structure, you need to decide the scheduling objective. It could be A) first-come-first-serve on the road as whole B) first-come-first-serve for each entry point C) maximize road occupancy D) minimize average wait time E) minimize worst case wait time E) any number of other objectives.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks! Good point. I would say first-come-first-serve for each entry point AND minimize average wait time. If its harder to do both, then just doing first-come-first-serve for each entry point. Would you know what algorithm I could use?

Comment: To enforce first-come-first-serve, you'll need to maintain a queue of cars for each entry point. Then the simplest scheduling algorithm (to choose which queue to service) is [round-robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling). [There are many other scheduling algorithms to choose from.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing))

Comment: I don't have a complete solution for minimizing average wait time. But one consideration is that a car entering at 1 and exiting at 10 is on the road for ten units of time, whereas a car entering at 3 and exiting at 4 is only on the road for one unit of time. So I believe that forcing long distance cars to wait will help to reduce average wait times. In other words, I don't think first-come-first-serve at each entry point can be used if the goal is to minimize the average wait time.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you! In case of round robin, for my use case - I am just trying to think of reasons if it may not be the best option. All the data is not just entering at one point, it's starting at different points flowing through to different points. So a car could enter at 8 and exit at 10, another at 4 exiting at 9. There is no in between state, for example we cannot just take a car in between and put it back in the queue. So would it still make sense? (Just thinking out loud, not sure if my reasoning is correct)

Comment: @user3386109 Also if I wanted to maximize road occupancy, would I use something like interval scheduling algiorithm? Or is there a different algorithm that would be a better fit for that?

Answer (score 1):

Outside of a top down master algorithm that decides what each car does and when, there is another approach that uses **agents** that interact with their environment and amongst themselves, with a limited set of **simple rules**. This often give rise to **complex behaviors**: You could maybe code simple rules into `car` objects, to define these interactions?

Maybe something like this:

**emerging behavior algorithm:**

1. a car moves forward if there are no cars just in front of it.
2. a car merges into a lane if there are no car right on its side (and
   maybe behind that slot too)
3. a car progresses towards its destination, and removes itself when destination is reached.

**proposed data structure**

- The data structure could be an indexed collection of "slots" along which a car moves towards a destination.
- Two data structures could intersect at a tuple of index values for each.
- Roads with 2 or more lanes could be modeled with coupled data structures...

**optimial numbers**

Determining the *max road use*, and *min time to destination* would require running the simulation several times, with varying parameters of the number of cars, and maybe variations of the rules.

A more elaborate approach would us continuous space on the road, instead of discrete slots.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your thoughts on it! I understand parts of it, will try to see what I can learn from the rest and how I can implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a `Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)` which will store each entry point as a node.
The problem of moving from one point to another can be thought of as a `graph-flow problem`, which has a number of algorithms for determining movement in a graph.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking into maximum flow problem but was not sure how that would fit with what I had but after you wrote that, I am going to rethink and see if that could work.